# Redirect to last page after saving new content with rules

Tags: rules, redirection

Drupal goes normally to the new node after creating or editing it. How to redirect to the last page where the user clicked on the node/add link using rules?
I tried different tokens with no success. Here is the rule:
Let's say we are on url: sitname/node/133
a user clicks on node/add/announcement
Rules: after saving, I need to go back to sitename/node/133
Rules:
After saving new content type:announcement

Action: Redirect to page sitename/node/ (token) not sure what to do here

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by taking another route. The original page I wanted to be redirected to is a node type page; on that page, there is a link to create a new node type (announcement).

I didn't mention that the announcement node is referencing the page node through the Entity reference module. To be redirected to the old node type page, I need to use the token [node:field-new-habit-ref:url] in the action section of the rule.